# Partition a list of positive and negative numbers into sets

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, algorithms, set-partition, linear-diophantine-equations

Given a list of $L$ integers, containing positive and negative number,how do I partition them into $K$ sets such that majority of elements in it are positive.
There are two cases in it :

1. When $K$ is odd.
2. When $K$ is even.

Now the majority of elements are considered to be positive when more than half of the elements in are positive. For simplicity, the cardinality of each set ($M$) is odd. ($L=K*M$).

Now we can take only the sign of integers i.e. represent positive with $+1$ and negative with $-1$. 
The elements in the set are to be consecutive so we make our list circular.

Instead of going through every possible consecutive sets, is there a efficient way to make those sets such that atleast $K/2$ are positive sets ?

Eg - 
1. $K$ (odd)= $3$

$1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 -1$

One way  : {$2,3.4$}, {$5,6,7$} , {$8,9,1$}

$2$ positive, $1$ negative so majorly positive

2. $K$ even= $4$

$-1 1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1$

There is no way possible to it to be major positive.

**EDIT** : How can we even tell if there is majority of positive sets ?

Comment: How do you propose to do this if only one of your integers is positive, and the other $L-1$ are all negative?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then we simply it's not possible or rather say it is the list of majority negative sets.

Comment: Work through the list, closing a partition as soon as it has one more positive than negative numbers in it. This gives you the maximum number of predominantly positive partitions.

Comment: @Thumbnail I get the idea but every $K$ set has to have exactly $M$ integers in it. Also the way has to be efficient and optimized further.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Thumbnail Can you help with the problem ?